# Сравнить данные и записать в базу

Tags: php

Делаю файл импорт, для того что бы товары не были с одинаковыми моделями, нужно сделать проверку сравнить с тем что пришло и то что есть.

Не могу понять почему когда я делаю `print_r($model);` я почему то получаю одно название если записать его в базу `$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . 1 . "', name = '" . $name . "'");`
 то записей получается столько сколько было и файле импорта, как можно сделать проверку что бы записи не дублировались с одинаковой моделью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На уникальные поля добавить `UNIQUE` ключи, а запись в БД делать или с помощью `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` (если новые записи надо игнорировать, оставляя более ранние) или с помощью `REPLACE IGNORE INTO ...` (если свежие должны затирать ранние). И не будет ни дублей, ни исключений при вставке.

Comment: Спасибо все работает

Answer (score 0):

Проверку можно сделать дополнительным запросом в БД - есть ли уже такая модель

```
SELECT product_id FROM ... WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'
```

или же сделать уникальный ключ на product_id  - тогда при добавлении записи в БД будет возбуждаться исключение, которое можно поймать в try catch .

Comment: Возбуждаться исключение =)